# containerd 1.4.9 Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I have installed `containerd 1.4.9` on CentOS steam 8 server.

based on this document https://containerd.io/docs/getting-started/. I have created default config file `containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml` like this.

after restarting containerd, when I run `crictl ps` Its throwing below error

```
FATA[0000] listing containers failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
```

How to fix this error? after fix this I want to join this node to Kubernets cluster `1.21.3` using `systemd` cfgroup.

Thanks
SR

Comment: The question was asked some time ago, could you tell if the question is still relevant or have you already solved this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same error today while upgrade kubelet on the worker nodes. Issue was within the default configuration. Note that containerd will run fine without any config. In my case I just wanted to enable systemd_cgroup.

`ctr plugin ls` showed that cri plugin was in error state with default configuration

Just a blank config with systemd_cgroup fixed issue for me:

```sh
cat > /etc/containerd/config.toml <<EOF
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  systemd_cgroup = true
EOF
systemctl restart containerd
```

Answer (score 2):

**Background Context About the error:**
From [gitlab.cncf.ci/containerd crictl.md docs](https://gitlab.cncf.ci/containerd/containerd/blob/a1138182d5d746351b3c321893001e33fd7fb4be/docs/cri/crictl.md)

"This could be that you are using an incorrect containerd configuration (maybe
from a Docker install). You will need to update your containerd configuration
to the containerd instance that you are running."

- I myself had installed docker, then yum installed crictl to investigate command syntax differences and ran into this.
- The resolution command posted in the linked doc only works if run as root, so here's a more generic version.

```
# Backup old containerd config (optional)
sudo mv /etc/containerd/config.toml /etc/containerd/config.bak

# Regenerate containerd config
sudo containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml

# Restart containerd
sudo systemctl restart containerd

# The above got it to work for me; but with some warnings 
# and ignorable errors that looked this this: 
sudo crictl ps
# WARN[0000] runtime connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead.
# ERRO[0002] connect endpoint 'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', make sure you are running as root and the endpoint has been started: context deadline exceeded
# WARN[0002] image connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead.
# ERRO[0004] connect endpoint 'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', make sure you are running as root and the endpoint has been started: context deadline exceeded
# CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                ATTEMPT             POD ID
# ^-- The last line represents correct output, which is why 
# I say ignorable warnings/errors, even the post command 
# exit code seeable using 'echo $?' exit code shows success

# What cleaned up the errors for me was copy pasting the following
echo """
runtime-endpoint: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
""" | sudo tee /etc/crictl.yaml

docker ps
# ^-- no more errors :)

# Note others may need to run one of these instead, based on their
# system's config, keep trying docker ps until one config works
echo """
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
""" | sudo tee /etc/crictl.yaml

echo """
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
""" | sudo tee /etc/crictl.yaml
```

Comment: solved the issue for me, but ps showed more errors

Comment: Just resetting the configuration worked for me:

sudo mv /etc/containerd/config.toml /etc/containerd/config.bak
sudo containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem related to errors in CRI plugins. You can check the status of the CRI plugin

```
ctr plugin ls
```

In the past I got the same problem due to devmapper problem, since devmapper is configured as default CRI snapshotter, CRI got error as well.

```
TYPE                                  ID                       PLATFORMS      STATUS
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1          devmapper                linux/amd64    error
io.containerd.grpc.v1                 cri                      linux/amd64    error
```

The problem gone after I reconfigure the devmapper snapshotter.

Removing the config (/etc/containerd/config.toml) works as well, but the containerd runs with default configuration, which was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

containerd-version: 1.6.20

cat > /etc/containerd/config.toml <<EOF
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
systemd_cgroup = false
EOF

设置为false 解决

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, on my end the correct parameter of containerd to set was not `systemd_cgroup` but:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            #[...]
            SystemdCgroup = true
```

which **is** a different setting in the config file.

**And** this is the actual setting that the official Kubernetes docs tell to set as true: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd-systemd